# Adding constraints relative to neighbors leads to conflict

Tags: ios, xcode

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, I was doing nothing but adding some distance constraints relative to the neighbors, and I got conflicts everywhere. How can I resolve this?

Xcode: Version 9.0 beta 3 (9M174d)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever defining constraints keep in mind following things.

1. Every view that you are defining constraint for requires its x position, y position, width and height defined.
2. Every view requires these positions defined, only and only by one constraint. (Maximum one constraint per dimension i.e. x,y,widht,height)
3. If there are more constraints defining any of these 4 values there will be conflicts.
4. If you are trying to give constraint of a target view relative to some source view, the source view itself must have already fixed its constraints. (I think this one might be the issue with your code).

You can always check the conflicts/ missing constraints in XCode. Click on the red button in left pan

[image]

You will be shown the missing constraints like this

[image]